# How to Restart Rails Production Servers After Code Deployment w/o Downtime

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In Rails, what is the best strategy to restarting app servers like Thin after a code deployment through a Capistrano script. I would like to be able to deploy code to production servers without fearing that a user might see the 500.html page.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Unicorn](http://unicorn.bogomips.org/) is supposed to have rolling restarts built in. I have not setup a unicorn stack yet but http://sirupsen.com/setting-up-unicorn-with-nginx/ looks like a good start.

Comment: Apache + Passenger combo is not a complete solution for rolling restarts. You will notice a delay in response time when the passenger instances are restarting. Unicorn instances do not start taking request until they are ready which means your users should not even experience a delay.

Answer (score 9):

I found this question while looking for an answer. Because I wanted to stick with Thin, none of the answers here suited my needs. This fixed it for me:

`thin restart -e production --servers 3 --onebyone --wait 30`

Answer (score 4):

The way I used to do the production servers are with apache and passenger. thats a industry standard setup and will allow you to deploy new versions with out a down time

Once everything is correctly setup all you have to do is, go to app directory

create a file called restart.txt in /tmp dir.

Ex: touch tmp/restart.txt

read more here http://www.modrails.com/

http://jimneath.org/2008/05/10/using-capistrano-with-passenger-mod_rails.html

http://www.zorched.net/2008/06/17/capistrano-deploy-with-git-and-passenger/

http://snippets.dzone.com/posts/show/5466

HTH

sameera

Comment: Seems like a great built in feature for passenger. Too bad I am currently running Thin/Nginx combo